# Can't enable pdo_sqlite

Tags: php, linux, sqlite

I've run `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite` , `phpinfo()` shows that sqlite3 is installed, but when I try to connect to it I get:

```
PDOException::could not find driver
```

When I enable it in apache2 php.ini file

```
extension = pdo_sqlite.so 
extension = sqlite.so
```

it doesn't change anything. Moreover - when I add this same lines into cli php.ini I get

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I've run out of ideas. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart the apache?

Comment: yep I did and that haven't change anything

Comment: Do you have the libraries?

Comment: which libraries? I've installed sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Load the **PHP pdo module** first, correcting the CLI symbolic links that where broken after *apt dist-upgrade*:

```
cd /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
ln -s ../../mods-available/pdo.ini 10-pdo.ini
```

**NOTE:** Via Web browser the phpinfo() return that all modules are loaded without erros so I compare /etc/php5/cli vs. /etc/php5/apache2 to see what is the difference.

**After:**

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2017 19:40:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

**Before:**

On my **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bits** appears the following warnings:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d# php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_pgsql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_odbc.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_odbc.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
```